# Set an attribute to an class's attribute where the latter is returned from a class method

Tags: python

I have the following code that takes two lists `a` and `b`, and returns a `Diff.diff` attribute, which is a list with three `dict()` in there. I want to be able to access each `dict` by using an attribute of an attribute as `Diff.diff.a`, `Diff.diff.b` etc.

Now `Diff.diff` is a working attribute when I create a new instance of `Diff` class. However, I get the error that

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'

on the line in `def __init__(...` starting to define that sub-attributes

```
class Diff(object):   

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = dict(a)
        self.b = dict(b)

        Diff.diff = Diff.set_diff(self)
        Diff.diff.a = Diff.diff[0]
        Diff.diff.b = Diff.diff[1]
        Diff.diff.c = Diff.diff[2]

    def set_diff(self):
        # do something with self.a and self.b here
        return [{}, {}, {}] # returns a list with three items
```

I've tried searching for this issue and honestly I don't know what search terms to use... Hope this is not a repeated question.

---

**EDIT:**

**My Solutions:**

Note my code uses `alpha` `beta` `gamaa` instead of `a` `b` `c`.

```
class DiffList(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        assert isinstance(a, list) and len(a) == 3
        self.alpha = DiffListItem(a[0])
        self.beta = DiffListItem(a[1])
        self.gamma = DiffListItem(a[2])


class Diff(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        assert isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list)
        self.a = dict(a)
        self.b = dict(b)
        self.diff = DiffList(self.set_diff())

    def set_diff(self):
        # return the list with 3 dicts
        return a
```

Now `Diff.diff.alpha` etc. returns a dict in the list as expected. Although this list is wrapped in a `DiffListItem` object that has a function that prints an ordered list.

```
class DiffListItem(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        assert isinstance(a, dict)        
        self.a = a

    def ordered_list(self):
        # Take a dict and sort by its value, returns a ordered list with entries
        # as lists as [key, value]
        keys = sorted(self.a, key=self.a.get, reverse=1)
        res = [[key, self.a[key]] for key in keys]    
        return res
```

Hope this is helpful to others. I'm rather new to programming and haven't done much OOP yet. Python is giving me a great introduction to what's capable.

Comment: You cannot set arbitrary attributes on a list; why do you expect that to work? And why are you trying to set an attribute on the `Diff` *class* object?

Comment: You know that, the values on the class will be overwritten whenever an object of `Diff` is created (since you are modifying it in `__init__`), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Diff.diff` is a `list`, which you can't access by attribute. Instead, you could create a new object with those attributes. With the `DiffList` (or some better name; it isn't a `list`) defined as:

```
class DiffList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = {}
        self.b = {}
        self.c = {}
```

You should probably *use* this as an instance, rather than class, attribute:

```
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = dict(a)
    self.b = dict(b)
    self.diff = DiffList() # no need for a separate method
    self.diff.a # ...
```

Then you can access it later:

```
diff = Diff(a, b)
diff.diff.a # ...
```

Comment: This is closest to what I want. I thought this method required some kind of inheritance from `Diff` so that `Diff.diff` is a child of it. But apparently you don't have to. I was thinking that `Diff.diff` has always been an object of its own kind instead of a list.. all makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `set_diff` is a Python `list` object. `list` objects are a kind of data structure that allows for accessing entries positionally, based on their location in the data structure, much like the row of a matrix from math class (except that the "entries" can be any type of object).

Your code is asking for the `list` object that goes by the name `Diff.diff` to possess an attribute `a` that is a reference to the 0th entry, and so on. But this is not the type of data access supported by the `list` class.

Instead, you could use a particular data type called a `namedtuple` with named attributes `a`, `b`, and `c`. In that case, your code would look like this:

```
class Diff(object):   

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = dict(a)
        self.b = dict(b)
        self.diff = self.set_diff(self)

    def set_diff(self):
        # do something with self.a and self.b here
        from collections import namedtuple
        diff_tuple = namedtuple('diff_tuple', 'a b c')
        return diff_tuple({}, {}, {}) # returns a tuple with three named items
```

Comment: I accepted the answer above because I thought `namedtuple` was something that I had to define myself. Turns out it's a default type! Thanks for your help and I'll definitely be trying this type next time.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you want to create something like that:

```
class Diff(object):   
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = dict(a)
        self.b = dict(b)

    #Do something here that modifies the diff.a, diff.b and diff.c 
    #attributes of the class like adding the dict to them

    def set_diff(self):
        # do something with self.a and self.b here
        return [{}, {}, {}] # returns a list with three items
```

This way by typing Diff.diff.a event without creating any object of class Diff ) you will have this *attributes of attributes*

Comment: I didn't expected to work, just try to show how to create attributes shared by elements of the same class. But why it will raise the `NameError` (so I learn a little bit... :D )?

Comment: Because the name `diff` doesn't exist in the scope of the class `Diff`. If you wanted them to be class attributes, just `a = None` would have sufficed, then they can be accessed via `Diff.a`.

Comment: 1) Because `diff` is not defined. Python names are case sensitive. 2) Because you can't access a class name from within the class definition (`Diff.a = None` won't work either). However, you *can* do `a = None` inside of the class definition. This will define a class variable that can be accessed via `self` after instantiation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I always forget that from Python, thanks

Comment: @JoelCornett it is better to access class attributes via `ClassName`, otherwise they can get overwritten by instance attributes.